# Traverse in array one by one in php

Tags: php

I have array and table structure where i have show the status one by one.

condition

-> for first time only first row will show Start other rows will be Pending.

-> once first row status will be End than next row will be enable and it will show Start. below rows will be Pending or disable.

How can I traverse in array step by step to check previous array and next array in PHP?

```
     <table>
      <tr><th>Process</th></tr>
     <?php foreach($productionPlanningQueueProduct as $key=>$processStep){ ?>
     <tr><td>
     <?php 
     $lable="start"; 
     $lable="process";
     $lable="end";
     echo $lable;
     ?>

     </td></tr>
       <?php }?>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use condition.

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Process</th></tr>
    <?php $prevArray = []; $secondArray = []; $thirdArray = []; ?>
 <?php foreach($productionPlanningQueueProduct as $key=>$processStep){ ?>
 <tr><td>
 <?php 
 if(empty($prevArray) && empty($secondArray) && empty($thirdArray)) {
    //write array
    $prevArray = $processStep;
  }
  elseif($prevArray && empty($secondArray) && empty($thirdArray)) {
    if(in_array('start', $prevArray)) {
            //to something
            $secondArray = $processStep;
            $prevArray = [];
    }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this and not I have resolved my issued.

```
       $previousValue=null;
       foreach($productionPlanningQueueProduct as $key=>$processStep){
       if($previousValue && $previousValue !=null) {
       echo $previousValue;
         }
       $previousValue = $processStep['production_process_step']; 
        }
```